# Microsoft photo editor - No file format information can be found in the registry (registry policy)

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, group-policy, windows-registry, microsoft-office

I have Windows Server 2003 and my users are running XP. When I installed Microsoft office 2000 the photo editor said "No file format information can be found in the registry". I Googled it and I found [this site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260151). It's wonderful but the problem is I want to add the registry key by GPO to avoid applying it by hand to each PC.

I created new GPO open properties
`Computer configuration --> Windows setting --> Security setting --> Registry` and I added the new key, which on Windows XP is normally in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Graphics Filters` but I can't find the key. How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

The GPO allows you to set the security on Registry keys, it does not create Registry keys. You need to create a custom ADM containing your registry key and add that ADM to your GPO. There are probably a number of ways to do this but I've used [NUTS](http://yizhar.mvps.org) for this many times. You can export the relevant Registry key to a file and have NUTS convert that to an ADM file that you can then import into your GPO.